# Moving All Data From One Dynamic Created Table To Another Excluding Some Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am creating two identical tables dynamically from JSON. 
Lets Call Them `Test1.Table , Test2.Table`.

`Test.Table1` is then loaded with data in it's columns by someone else.

My Issue is that now, I want to create a stored procedure that creates a stored procedure that takes all the data from `Test.Table1` and inserts them into `Test.Table2` , which would be easy, except I don't want to take all the columns from `Test.Table1` , I want all but 3 of them.

I can't do a `SELECT (col1, col2, col4, col5...etc) INTO Test.Table2 FROM Test.Table1` because the columns are dynamic every time, and the table already exists.

I can't do use a temporary table to move `Test.Table1`'s data into and drop the columns I don't want and insert it into `Test.Table2` Because the columns wouldn't match up.

Comment: You need to query the meta-data of the tables to know which columns they contain and then build your insert statement as needed. And given the question, this might be beyond your abilties. And one must question the wisdom of this approach. Is your logic based on shared names alone? [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will have a row for each column - that is your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick script to get you started. I created two tables in tempdb with slightly different table structures and wrote it such that you can insert from the first one to the second one where the columns match up. You can change the table structure and the query will change accordingly. The query is based on the second table. This is part of the design, you may wish to swap that around.

```
Use tempdb;
Go

If OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##Temp1') is not null Drop Table ##Temp1
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Temp2') is not null Drop Table ##Temp2

Create Table ##Temp1 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)
Create Table ##Temp2 (col1 int, col2 int, col4 int)

Declare @max int
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Select @max = max(ordinal_position)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = '##Temp2' 

Select @sql = 
STRING_AGG(
case when ordinal_position = 1 then 'Insert into ##Temp2 ('+COLUMN_NAME+',' 
when ORDINAL_POSITION = @max then COLUMN_NAME +')'
else COLUMN_NAME+', ' end,'') + string_agg (
case when ordinal_position = 1 then ' Select '+COLUMN_NAME+', ' when ORDINAL_POSITION = @max 
Then COLUMN_NAME +' From ##Temp1' else COLUMN_Name + ', ' end,'')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = '##Temp2'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Hope this helps.